# Is there a solution to count and recount on a condition in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to find out how many rides a car undertook during a day and giving each ride which is written in a new row a "ride counter" indicating the sequence of the car ride during that day. I created a column indicating whether the ride was the first of a day ("Is_first_ride"). If so, the new column I want to create called "#_of_ride" should start counting from 1 if it was the first ride of the day until the next first ride of the day is reached. I already tried the following:

```
def counter(first_ride):
    counter = 1
    while first_ride != 1:
        counter += 1
        return counter
    return 1


df["#_of_ride"] = df.apply (lambda x: counter(x[df["Is_first_ride"]]), axis=1)
```

But this returns a Value Error - Series is Ambigious.

in the end I hope to create something that looks like this:

| car | date | Is_first_ride | #_of_ride |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Ford | 20.1.2021 | 1 | 1 |
| Ford | 20.1.2021 | 0 | 2 |
| Ford | 20.1.2021 | 0 | 3 |
| Ford | 20.1.2021 | 0 | 4 |
| Fiat | 20.1.2021 | 1 | 1 |
| Fiat | 20.1.2021 | 0 | 2 |
| Fiat | 20.1.2021 | 0 | 3 |
| Fiat | 20.1.2021 | 0 | 4 |
| Ford | 21.1.2021 | 1 | 1 |
| Ford | 21.1.2021 | 0 | 2 |

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can make use of `cumsum` in combination with boolean arrays. We use the boolean arrays both for making the groups of rides, plus the ride counter.

```
fr = df['Is_first_ride'].eq(1)
df['nr_of_ride'] = df['Is_first_ride'].ne(1).groupby(fr.cumsum()).cumsum().add(1)
```

```
    car       date  Is_first_ride  nr_of_ride
0  Ford  20.1.2021              1           1
1  Ford  20.1.2021              0           2
2  Ford  20.1.2021              0           3
3  Ford  20.1.2021              0           4
4  Fiat  20.1.2021              1           1
5  Fiat  20.1.2021              0           2
6  Fiat  20.1.2021              0           3
7  Fiat  20.1.2021              0           4
8  Ford  21.1.2021              1           1
9  Ford  21.1.2021              0           2
```

---

Or a second option where we leverage `cumcount` (thanks Shubham) and the fact that `Is_first_ride` is already suitable to do a cumsum (so we skip `fr = ...`)

```
df['nr_of_ride'] = (
    df['Is_first_ride'].ne(1)
    .groupby(df['Is_first_ride'].cumsum())
    .cumcount().add(1)
)
```